# Leaflet - Plate Carree and Tropical belt

Tags: leaflet

For a map design I need to find out if it possible.

Are there any tile servers which support Equirectangular/Plate Carree projection?
Also i need to add a layer with the tropical belt.

The Map example is build with an small GeoJson file and append the tropical belt as image. But on detailed GeoJson i think the pageload and performance is not ideal. So i tend to tiles.

I have created a basic code which shows the required bounds.

```
<div id="map" style="width:512px; height: 340px;"></div>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var $mapContainer = $('#map'), 
        widthToHeightRatio = 0.664;

    var map = L.map($mapContainer[0], {
        attributionControl: false,
        zoomControl: false,
        doubleClickZoom: false,
        scrollWheelZoom: false,
        boxZoom: false,
        dragging: false,
        center: [0, 0],
        zoom: 1
    });

    L.tileLayer(
        'https://stamen-tiles-{s}.a.ssl.fastly.net/toner-background/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
    ).addTo(map);

    map.setMaxBounds([
        [75.5, -158],
        [-20, 180]
    ]);
});
</script>
```

JsFiddle with map example: https://jsfiddle.net/hieblmedia/rmd5x827/

The targets are:

- Must work in alle modern Browsers including down to IE8 (better IE7)
- Equirectangular/Plate Carree projection,
- Tropical belt layer,
- Colors: Map in grey and Tropical belt in
- Boundaries without Antarctica (already done in jsfiddle),
- Responsiveness (width: 100%, height: auto) and always fit to the boundaries on resize.

I have searched a lot, but i struggle to get any results to perform all the targets.
Maybe the only way is a own tile Server? Or is LeafletJs just the wrong choice of library to perform the targets without an custom map services?

Any suggesstions are welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to achieve this. You are making a very general question with little detail, so it's difficult to provide specifics.

You can, for example:

- Create your own tiles

  - Get some country boundaries or coastline definition like e.g. from [NaturalEarth data](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/)
  - Create a polygon for the tropical area, and calculate the intersection of the landmass
  - Use e.g. geoserver/mapserver/mapproxy/tilemill to render and serve the tiles
- Overlay some semitransparent polygon over the tropical area.

  - Use the intersection described above, or
  - Hack the rendering so a custom compositing method is used between the vector data and raster tiles
- Manipulate the colour of the tiles on-the-fly with. For example, doing so in `Leaflet.TileLayer.GL` looks like:

  ```
  var vertexShader = `
  attribute vec2 aVertexCoords;
  attribute highp vec2 aCRSCoords;
  attribute vec2 aTextureCoords;
  varying vec2 vTextureCoords;
  varying highp vec2 vCRSCoords;
  void main(void) {
      gl_Position = vec4(aVertexCoords , 1.0, 1.0);
      vTextureCoords = aTextureCoords;
      vCRSCoords = aCRSCoords;
  }
  `

  var fragmentShader = `
  precision highp float;
  uniform sampler2D uTexture0;
  varying vec2 vTextureCoords;
  varying highp vec2 vCRSCoords;

  void main(void) {
      vec4 texelColour = texture2D(uTexture0, vec2(vTextureCoords.s, vTextureCoords.t));
      vec4 stop;

      // Color stops. The alpha value represents the latitude minimum for that RGB colour stop.
      // Latitudes are expressed in EPSG:3875 units, not in degrees of latitude.
      vec4 stops[5];
      stops[0] = vec4(0.444, 0.691, 1.0,   -20037508);    // Blue-ish north of -90
      stops[1] = vec4(0.333, 0.666, 0.333, -10015051);    // Green-ish north of -66.5
      stops[2] = vec4(0.9, 0.75, 0.35,      -2571663);    // Orange-ish north of -22.5
      stops[3] = vec4(0.333, 0.666, 0.333,   2571663);    // Green-ish north of 22.5
      stops[4] = vec4(0.444, 0.691, 1.0,    10015051);    // Blue-ish north of 66.5

      // Find which colour stop we want to use
      for (int i=0; i < 5; i++) {
          if (vCRSCoords.y > stops[i].a) {
              stop = stops[i];
          }
      }

      // Multiply the black in the texel by the stop colour
      gl_FragColor = vec4(
          vec3(1.0) - (texelColour.rgb) * (vec3(1.0) - stop.rgb)
      , 1.0);
  }
  `

          var tileSize = 256;

          var map = L.map('map').fitWorld();

          var antitoner = L.tileLayer.gl({
              vertexShader: vertexShader,
              fragmentShader: fragmentShader,
              tileUrls: ['http://{s}.tile.stamen.com/toner/{z}/{x}/{y}.png']
          }).addTo(map);
  ```

You can see a working demo of the last method at http://ivansanchez.gitlab.io/Leaflet.TileLayer.GL/demo/demo-tropical.html

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. This helps me a lot. The problem with WebGL is the lack support in IE.
Currently is use a simple GeoJson file with LonLat projection (CRS Simple). This view is required.
Is there a alternative way to the WebGL solution, except the own tile server?

Comment: If you have more context, please edit your original question and include it there.

Comment: I have changed the original question